# How to remove xpath from extract_first() output?

Tags: python, xpath, strip

I'm new to Python, so apologies in advance for any idiocy.

I'm scraping information from a website, and am extracting elements using .extract_first().

What I wanted the output to be was just the text of the element, ie 'Bob Smith'. But instead, it seems like the xpath is being printed around the name:

**Relevant code:**

```
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
name = sel.xpath('//li[@class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"]').extract_first()
if name:
     name = name.strip() 
print(name)
```

**Output:**

```
'<li class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words">\n            Bob Smith\n          </li>'
```

I tried finding a solution online, but haven't found one that deals with this issue in the context of extract_first() . How do I get rid of the xpath so the output being printed is just the element text? Thanks.

Comment: You have to mention which scraper you are using, Scrapy, Beautifulsoup, Selenium or something else. If it's Scrapy try passing "/text()" in the xpath. Please check https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
name = sel.xpath('normalize-space(//li[@class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"])').extract_first()
```

My output from the html in your question:

> Bob Smith